# Filter Subform via Texbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a simple code to filter a sub-form that has a several thousand lines of items.

```
Private Sub LampSearch_Change()

Dim strfilter As String

    Me.Refresh
    
    strfilter = "[SalesText] like '*" & Me.LampSearch & "'"
    
    Me.LampDataSheetSubForm.Form.Filter = strfilter
    Me.LampDataSheetSubForm.Form.FilterOn = True
    
    Me.LampSearch.SelStart = Nz(Len(Me.LampSearch), 0)

End Sub
```

This works, but it isn't quite doing what I want. The only way I can seem to describe what it is doing is "like" rather than "contains". So if I search say, LED, it will only find specifically "LED", not "LEDA19".

What do I need to change to get it to search for records that "contain" the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need (both a leading and) a trailing star:

```
strfilter = "[SalesText] like '*" & Me.LampSearch & "*'"
```

Comment: Perfect! It is always the little things.